# Best PHP Function To Output One Choice Out of Many

Tags: php, if-statement

I'm importing a product list, and each item has a department number.  Each number correlates with a department, i.e.

1. Handguns
2. Used Handguns
3. Used Long Guns
4. Tasers
5. Sporting Long Guns

There are 43 departments. Would I just do one long if statement like:

```
`<?php
if ($var = 1) 
echo "Handguns";
else
if ($var = 2) 
echo "Used Handguns";
```

etc.....
    ?>`

EDIT: I'm able to get an if statement like this to work:

`function test($cat) {
           if ($cat = 33) 
echo "Clothing";
    }`

but using any array like this:

`$departments = [
33 => Clothing,
];

function getDepartment($id, $departments) {
           echo $departments[$id];
    }`

I've been unable to get that to work.  I'm using wordpress and putting this in functions.php and calling the function from a plugin.

Should I just stick with a big if Statement?

2nd EDIT: Got it to work by including the array inside the function:

```
function getDepartment($id, $departments) {

$departments = [
"1" => "Handguns",
"2" => "Used Handguns",
"3" => "Used Long Guns",
"4" => "Tasers",
"5" => "Sporting Long Guns",
"6" => "SOTS ",
 ...
"41" => "Upper Receivers/Conv Kits",
"42" => "SBR Barrels and Uppers ",
"43" => "Upper/Conv Kits High Cap"
];

    if (isset($departments[$id])) {
        return $departments[$id];
    }
    return 'Uncategorized'; 
}
```

and inside wpallimport, the category call looked liked this: [getDepartment({column_4[1]})]

Comment: How is the product list stored? In a database? In a text file? As an array?

Comment: @Amal I'm using Wordpress so the function will be put in functions.php and will be called from a plugin... Because of how the plugin works, I think I can only have one variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an array of the departments using their ID as their array key. Then you can access them using basic array variable syntax:

```
$departments = array(
  1 => Handguns,
  2 => Used Handguns,
  3 => Used Long Guns,
  4 => Tasers,
  5 => Sporting Long Guns
);

$var = 2;
echo $departments[$var]; // prints "Used Handguns"
```

You can construct this array however you like. It can be hardcoded in a config file or more likely created from a SQL query.

Just make sure that the key exists in your array *before* you try to access it or else you get an undefined index error message. You probably would be wise to place this in a function so you can abstract this code and reduce duplicated code on each attempt to access this array.

```
function getDepartment($id, $departments) {
    if (isset($departments[$id])) {
        return $departments[$id];
    }
    return 'Invalid Department'; // or whatever you want if the value doesn't exist
}

echo getDepartment(2); // prints "Used Handguns"
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm trying it out now!

Comment: Blarg, ok, so apparently I can't just put the array directly in functions.php? (I'm using wordpress).  Where would be the easiest place to put the array?

Comment: I put the following in my functions.php, all it's returning is "Uncategorized" for the category...  Any idea what's wrong?                                                         function getDepartment($id, $departments) {
    if (isset($departments[$id])) {
        return $departments[$id];
    }
    return 'Uncategorized'; // or whatever you want if the value doesn't exist
}


                          
$departments = [
33 => Clothing,
];

Comment: @Alteredorange Check the value of `$id` and make sure it is was you expect. It probably isn't.

Comment: Do I need to define where the array is located?  Inside the plugin, it calls the PHP like this: [getDepartments({category_Id},(should the path to the array go here?)]

Comment: You don't need to define where it is located. You just need to make sure whatever file that contains that array is included so you have access to it.